# Python v3 , Beautifoulsoup - multiple div tags with same name

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser") # BeautifulSoup(markup, "lxml")
 items = soup.find_all("div","_3u1 _gli _uvb", recursive=True)
   for item in items: 
      abouts = item.find_all("div", {"class":"_glo"}, recursive = True)[0].text
   print (abouts)
```

---

HTML page:

```
          <div class="_glo">
            <div>
              <div class="_ajw">
                <div class="_52eh">
                    "text
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="_ajw">
                <div class="_52eh">
                    "text"
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="_ajw">
                <div class="_52eh">
                   "text"
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Afternoon , i am trying to scrape a webpage using beautifullsoup, python. I need al the "text" strings in a separate variable. When i print abouts i get :"text text text" I want it to be seperated.

Kind regards

Comment: post the final expected result

Comment: i want it : text1 :"text" -> text2 : "text of next div" -> text3 : "text of next div" untill there are no more div classes .... sometimes its 1 div tag with same name other times its 4 , 3 , ...

Comment: while you have the same `text` value for all divs - your final output is not representative. Try to post a more distinguishable content

Comment: You are choosing the wrong class to parse the content. Try this `for item in soup.find_all(class_="_52eh"): print(item.text)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
items = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'_ajw'})
dict = {}
for i in range(len(items)):
    dict['text'+str(i+1)] = item[i].find('div', attrs={'class':'_52eh'}).text
print(dict)
```

This will give you something like this:

```
{'text1': text, 'text2': text, 'text3': text}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use soup.select to apply a class selector to the html. It is a fast method to get a list of the appropriate elements by class

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
  <div class="_glo">
            <div>
              <div class="_ajw">
                <div class="_52eh">
                    "text
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="_ajw">
                <div class="_52eh">
                    "text"
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="_ajw">
                <div class="_52eh">
                   "text"
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          '''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')

items = [item.text.strip() for item in soup.select('._52eh')]
print(items)
```